# Java: not printing lines which start with certain character

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So basicly what I'm intending to do is read information from the agree1out file, which contains following information:

> 1|1
>
> 2|0

The following piece of code hooks into my mySQL database, using the first 2 numbers (before "|") to get `xf.user.user_id`.

Currently String print is:

> equalsdavid 1 6af87ef8-e620-4d08-8320-183fc469eb0d
>
> user 0 ac899bce-4a87-4977-957c-05013534b25b

I need a way to remove lines where the second part of the string is less than 1.
Now I tried doing something like, but since I'm here you can probably tell it didn't work:

```
  temp = temp.replaceAll("(?m)^0.*", "");
```

Here is the code:

```
  package io.chuchoter.stats2;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import io.chuchoter.core.Main;

    public class RATE2_agree {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String line = null;
     
        try {
            
            PrintStream p = new PrintStream(new File(Main.agree2out));
            System.setOut(p);
            
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(Main.agree1out);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                
                String[] parts = line.split("|");
                String part1 = parts[0];
                String part3 = parts[2];
                
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Main.host, Main.uName, Main.uPass);
                
                Statement rstmt = con.createStatement();
                String r = "SELECT * FROM `xf_user` WHERE `user_id` = " + part1 + ";";
                ResultSet rs = rstmt.executeQuery(r);
                
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    String username = rs.getString("username");
                    
                    String print = username + " " + part3 + " " + uuid;
                    System.out.println(print);
                }
            }   

            bufferedReader.close();         
                  
        }
        
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file");
        }
        
        catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string "1|1", when you apply a split

```
String[] parts = line.split("|");
```

you get an array of size 2. Thus your code will go like this

```
String[] parts = line.split("|");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part3 = parts[1];         
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Main.host, Main.uName, Main.uPass);

Statement rstmt = con.createStatement();
String r = "SELECT * FROM `xf_user` WHERE `user_id` = " + part1 + ";";
ResultSet rs = rstmt.executeQuery(r);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
     String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
     String username = rs.getString("username");
     String print = username + " " + part3 + " " + uuid;
     if(Integer.parseInt(part3) >= 0)
         sb.append(print + "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but I am actually looking for a way to remove lines from a string which contain a certain part, I already figured I would have to split the lines, but what would I do to check if the second part of a line is <0 and if that's true, remove that line from the String?

Comment: Updated the solution. If the value of second part of your line is less than 3, the code will just ignore that line. Else, it appends it to the stringbuilder and then prints the entire output at once.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, except for the fact I changed the ">= 0" to "> 0".